# How does Aristotle show that 'particular deductions can be reduced to universal deductions in the first figure'?

Tags: logic, aristotle

In *Prior Analytics* I.7, 29b15-20, Aristotle states that

> And so since the syllogisms in the middle figure can all be reduced to
> the universal syllogisms in the first figure, and the particular
> syllogisms in the first figure to the universal syllogisms in the
> second, it is evident that the particular syllogisms [in the first
> figure] can also be reduced to the universal syllogisms in that
> figure.

But I can't see where Aristotle demonstrates this, and I'm struggling to see how it's valid. Can anyone help explain this?

Comment: You can't really speak on figures without describing the MOOD of the syllogism. Let's recall Aristotle considered the first figure with the mood AAA the perfect syllogism. With the perfect syllogism there is no need to worry about validity. Validity would be automatically covered. So there is that obvious reason to try to put every syllogism in the perfect syllogism. The order here is important.All propositions can be converted using immediate inferences. With that said all syllogisms can be converted into the perfect syllogism using special techniques. We wouldn't need the other way around.

Comment: What this allows is the opportunity to change an invalid argument into a valid form. Valid here doesn't mean the syllogism is true in reality. The Square of Opposition is important as well as the immediate inference rules that I mentioned above. Those should be known doing Aristotelian logic. Mathematical logic aka modern logic for instance doesn't necessarily use the same methods.The medevial philosophers invented a famous mnemonic poem to convert every syllogism into a valid syllogism. So if you don't see a direct proof in Aristotle's works it is because some other information was expected.

Comment: See [Aristotle's Logic: The Deductions in the Figures](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#MetProPerDedConRed): "In the proofs for imperfect deductions, Aristotle says that he “reduces” each case to one of the perfect forms and that they are thereby “completed” or “perfected”. These completions are either probative (*deiktikos*: a modern translation might be “direct”) or through the impossible."

Comment: A huge literature is available: John Corcoran, [A Mathematical Model of Aristotle’s Syllogistic (1973)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249941940_A_Mathematical_Model_of_Aristotle's_Syllogistic) and John Corcoran, [Completeness of an Ancient Logic (1972)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38380270_Completeness_of_an_Ancient_Logic) and John Corcoran, [Aristotle's natural deduction system (1974)](https://philpapers.org/archive/CORAND.pdf)

Comment: For an example in the original text, see Aristotle, *Prior An*, 27a5-27a15.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting, however, relatively neglected, side of Aristotle's thought. We see that Aristotle meticulously works out not only the theory of syllogism, but also a metatheory over it. While I shall outline a sample of his arguments (a deduction *per impossibile*), I strongly recommend to go over Robin Smith's SEoP article *[Aristotle’s Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/)*. Smith has persistently studied Aristotle's logical heritage and is one of the main sources on Aristotle's metatheory. The following is actually an explication of a part of his formulation.

It should be remarked that 'reduce' and the original word 'ἀνάγειν' is a Greek-Latin etymological correspondency, let alone a literal translation, thus, quite misleading for the contemporary reader. A more explanatory English word would be 'lead up' which matches its Greek usage well: Aristotle does not claim that the syllogisms can be replaced by universal syllogisms, but they lead up to the universal syllogisms to be complete (τέλειος; the connotation as 'self-standing' should be considered to grasp the context better).

Let us begin the mood *Darii* (**I distort** the order to make the argument more conspicuous, beware):

All *x* are *y*, Some *z* are *x* ⟹ Some *z* are *y*

Then, we state the mood *Camestres*, one of the universal syllogisms in the second figure:

All *x* are *y*, No *z* is *y* ⟹ No *z* is *y*

We observe that one premiss is shared by *Darii*. We adjoin the other premiss as an assumption, likewise the conclusions of both moods, to obtain:

All *x* are *y*, Some *z* are *x*, No *z* is *y* ⟹ Some *z* are *y*, No *z* is *y*

We have reached an impossible statement. Hence, our assumption is false.

The contradictory of [**E**-type is **I**-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#:%7E:text=a%20sorites%20argument.-,Types,-%5Bedit%20source%5D). Therefore, we have demonstrated that 'some *z* are *y*' is valid. Schematically (this notation reads *y***A***x* as 'y belongs to every x', i.e., the first variable stands for predicate, the second variable for subject in a sentence):

*y***A***x*, *x***I***z* ⟹ *y***I***z*